# Android rotation disturbs my screen animation

Tags: android, layout, rotation

I have got a card flip animation witch works fine, the only problem that I am facing is that every time I flip my device (from landscape to portrait and vice versa) my screen layout is recreated again, that means: if I was in second face of the card, when I flip my device the first reappears, And I want the second to still be displayed how can I handle that?

Comment: You need to save variables through your savedInstanceState bundle so that on orientation change you can determine what state the cards where in before rotation by checking the savedInstanceState bundle in onCreate

Comment: Basically my animation is about changing two layouts visibility, when the first is  gone the second is visible and vise versa, how can I save that?

Comment: Set primitives to tell you what layout is visible and save them in your bundle. For example, you could create an int, let's call it visibleLayout. If the first layout is visible, visibleLayout = 0, if the second layout is visible, visibleLayout = 1. Then in onCreate check your saved instance state bundle to checck your visible layout.

Comment: Great! thanks I am gonna try that thanks a lot I ve got just one more question , you are telling me to check that on the onCreate methode do you mean the onCreate of my activity? that means that every time my device is flipped the activity is recreated again? (sorry for my dummy question Im super beginner! )

Comment: By default, your activity is recreated every time you flip it

Comment: @blame521 is correct. When I get home I'll write a more complete answer if someone hasn't by then

Comment: You response have been very helpful!! I ve got a better understanding now! thanks a lot!

Comment: Supposed to say @bkane521 not blame521 but autocorrect is funny haha. Want to make sure credit goes where it's due :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to tell android that you will handle when the screen changes orientation, so that `onCreate()` is not called again when the screen changes orientations.  To do this, add an entry for the specific activity in your manifest file.  It should look something like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.package.name.Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.package.name.Parent" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.package.name.Parent" />
</activity>
```

the line `android:configChanges` is what I'm referring to

Comment: Note that if you have different layouts for landscape and portrait you'll have to handle the change yourself. `configChanges` should be a last-resort solution. From the Android documentation: "Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change." The link to Handling Runtime Changes is: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html